# Highchart update chart issue

Tags: angular, highcharts

I am fetching series data from API based on some scenarios and if in one of the scenario data is empty array Chart is not getting refreshed it still shows the previous value, not getting what is the correct approach to refresh chart

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
this.sink.add(this._store.pipe(select(coreSelector)).
  subscribe((data: ICore) => {
    if (data && data.hasOwnProperty(this.selectedZone)) {
      this.chartComponent.chartInstance.xAxis[0].
        setCategories(data[this.selectedZone].categories, false);
      this.updateSeries(data);
    } else {
      // this.chartComponent.chartInstance.xAxis[0].setCategories([], false);
      // this.chartComponent.chartInstance.series.forEach((chartSeries, index) => {
      //     this.chartComponent.chartInstance.series[index].setData([], false);
      // });
    }
  }));
}

updateSeries(data) {
    data[this.selectedZone].seriesData.forEach((series) => {
     this.chartComponent.chartInstance.series.forEach((chartSeries, index) => {
    if (seriesKeyMapping[series.seriesName] === chartSeries.name) {
      this.chartComponent.chartInstance.series[index].setData(series.data, false);
    }
  });
});
this.chartComponent.chartInstance.redraw();
}
```

I tried to setData as empty array but this is also not working as expected.
What is the best way to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Highcharts with Angular it is recommended to use the official highcharts-angular wrapper. With the wrapper, you wouldn't have to create your own methods to handle updates.

Here you can find a simple demo that will show you the optimal way to update your chart using the highcharts-angular: 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-optimal-way-to-update-gd7vv2

**Docs references:** 
https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular